# Telling Python to save a .txt file to a certain directory on linux

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to save a file in the QCTestFiles directory, but my script is not writing the files to the specified directory. Is my path file correct for Linux and if it is not how can I change my code to write and save a file in a different directory? My current script is running in the brperez location.

```
filename =  (GPN + '_' + inspector + '_' + date + '.txt')
save_path = 'c:/usr/local/home/brperez/QCTestFiles' 
complete_name = os.path.join(save_path, filename) 
file1 = open(complete_name, "w")
```

Comment: "but my script doesn't do that. " then what does it do?

Comment: I am trying to write it to the directory above, but the files are not being added to that directory

Comment: You sure you are in `linux` because the path is for `windows` and does it raise any error.

Comment: No error is raised when opening the file? **are you sure?** If you specify an invalid path to `open` it will always raise an error so if no error was raised then it opened something for writing...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that path is correct for linux. I can't remember ever preceding a linux path with 'c:', it's been a while since I spent a lot of time in a true linux env, but I suppose it could depend on what you are doing.

Do you have access to the machine? Navigate to the folder in terminal and type 'pwd' to get the proper path. Also, make sure your application has write permissions to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct for linux. There is no concept of a 'c:' drive in linux. You should only have to specify the path, e.g. '/usr/local/home/brperez/QCTestFiles'

For more information about drive naming in linux, take a look at this question, and the links in the top answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56929/what-is-the-linux-drive-naming-scheme

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Linux, your path will not have a drive letter, it will just be something like /usr/local/home/brperez.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

giving that you're running your script in the `brperez` location, you can replace your snippet with the following one:

```
filename = (GPN + '_' + inspector + '_' + date + '.txt')
save_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'QCTestFiles')
complete_name = os.path.join(save_path, filename)
file1 = open(complete_name, "w")
```